# How to count values between zero in R?

Tags: r

I have something like this:

`v <- c(0, 0, 0.05, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 2, 4, 0.8, 0, 0)`

I need to count the number of elements between zero values, so i will get: 3, 4

First time posting here.. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `rle` :

```
v <- c(0, 0, 0.05, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 2, 4, 0.8, 0, 0)
with(rle(v != 0), lengths[values])
#[1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
table(rleid(v != 0)[v != 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option without using `rle`

```
> z <- which(v != 0)
> tapply(z, cumsum(diff(c(0, z)) != 1), length)
1 2
3 4
```

or

```
> attr(gregexpr("1+", paste0(+!!v, collapse = ""))[[1]], "match.length")
[1] 3 4
```